# JQuery if statement not working on nested elements?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Hey guy's I can't figure out why my code doesn't work when I have nested elements...

Here's my html code

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="head.js"></script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mock.css"
    />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="subMenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="button boxshadow">
                <a class="subnav" href="#">Test</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="button boxshadow">
                        <a class="subnav" href="#">Testing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button boxshadow">
                        <a class="subnav" href="#">Tested</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="button boxshadow">
                <a class="subnav" href="#">Works</a>
            </li>
            <li class="button boxshadow">
                <a class="subnav" href="#">Other</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="button boxshadow">
                        <a class="subnav" href="#">Other</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button boxshadow">
                        <a class="subnav" href="#">Other</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="button boxshadow">
                <a class="subnav" href="#">Last</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="button boxshadow">
                        <a class="subnav" href="#">Last1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button boxshadow">
                        <a class="subnav" href="#">Last2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button boxshadow">
                        <a class="subnav" href="#">Last3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="button boxshadow">
                        <a class="subnav" href="#">Last4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

my CSS

```
.button {
    background: url(images / button.jpeg) no - repeat;
    background - size: 100 % ;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 165px;
    text - align: center;
    left: 25px;
    margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

and my javascript/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').bind("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "0 0 10px 5px #B6B6B6");

        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() == "test".toLowerCase()) {
            a = "blah."
            b = "blah."
            c = "blah."
            d = "blah."
            e = "blah."
            f = "blah."

            handle(a, b, c, d, e, f);
        }
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() == "works".toLowerCase()) {
            a = "blah"
            b = "blah."
            c = "blah"
            d = "blah"
            e = "Blah"
            f = "Blah"

            handle(a, b, c, d, e, f);
        }

        $(this).bind("mouseout", function() {
            $(this).css("box-shadow", "5px 5px 10px #070707");
        })
    })
})​
```

So from this everything is working expect when i have sub items in my list like in "test" which has 2 sub lists, my if statement will work on "test if I remove the sub list exactly like "works". As soon as I add sub items to my main list my if statement stops working even though I know the mouseover is working cause it is working the .css part of the code..

Any ideas on what's happening here would be greatly appreciated.. I am new to JQuery and am moving my site to it rather than java script. thx

Comment: `"works".toLowerCase()`? why?

Comment: Yes, why ? IS enough `$(this).text().toLowerCase() === "test"`

Comment: I know redundant but at the time was just playing with the method to see how well it worked, originally this was just for testing, and is useless I know :P...

So now my question changes, I figured out that it's grabbing all three items text values, I know they are all under the same class and the jquery statement is grabbing $(this) based on class but I am still individually hovering over them, impossible to hover over all three at once, and the .css part of the code works on them all individually perfect... so why is it grabbing all three texts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can use .toLowerCase() directly on a string as it is a function part of the String object.

Thus, you know exactly its value since you hard code it, why using this function on the right part of the equation?

```
if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() == "test")
```

should solve your problem, to test it out you should try console.log(your condition).

**EDIT**

Based on your comment and your code, it seems to be a matter of selector and/or html structure. You target .button which is applied to an li which contains more li items.
You can "flatten" your html to the same level, or more simply, adapt your selector and classes.
But I think the best approach is the following :

```
$(this).find("a").first().text(); // or "a:first"
```

There is probably something prettier but you can understand where this is going? Using .first() to prevent going into the sub li.

Comment: Thx for your comment, You actually can use a method on a string that has been tested and true, I ran a quick block of code to display what this in $(this).text() and I found out it is grabbing the parent list and the sub list menu so basically with the sub menu's (even though they are their own element)..
$(this).text() is outputting "Test Testing Tested" hence why the if statement isn't working cause it is, just the method isn't producing the output i was expecting...

Comment: I would also suggest to change your selector to a.subnav because the event of "Test" might be applied to "Testing" and "Tested" as it is including inside your first li.button

Comment: It worked, thanks a bunch! I really didn't want to have to change my html layout or add another class to my html code. Thx again!!